# What benefit does lending the land give to China instead of giving it outright?

Tags: china, land

What benefit does lending the land give to China instead of giving it outright

> Last Wednesday, Premier Li Keqiang said a real estate protection
> provision that would ensure individual’s access to property under a
> 70-year lease would be renewed unconditionally is being drafted.
>
> This will help to quell ongoing fears that wealth garnered from one
> generation will be removed after the 70-year lease ends by the
> government. And while this does not address the fate of 20-year
> leases, the precedent set in Wenzhou may be replicated in other areas.

https://www.forbes.com/sites/sarahsu/2017/03/21/good-news-for-chinese-homeowners-premier-li-offers-some-clarity-on-land-leases/?sh=635216267b4a

Just renewing a lease does not allow China to make any money from this, so why is it being done if they won't get any significant financial gain from it? Or am I wrong on this? If not, then what are the benefits of doing this instead of giving the land outright, what are the cons? Do the benefits outweigh to costs?

Comment: Private land ownership seems to be limited by law in China.  Communism/Socialism and all that. https://www.lehmanlaw.com/resource-centre/faqs/real-property/is-it-correct-that-china-does-not-allow-private-ownership-of-real-property.html  https://blogs.loc.gov/law/2015/03/chinese-law-on-private-ownership-of-real-property/  A lease seems to sidestep the issue.

Comment: The leases are not for small monthly amounts. They are for huge lump sums compared to monthly and annual incomes. The answer is in your quote. The government doesn't want leases to end because it disruptive: "wealth garnered from one generation will be removed". The government does not want to get paid for the next 70 years, at least not in this way. The government can create new ways to collect money if they need to.

Comment: Another consideration is that the right to occupy is a depleting asset. A new law about leases can potentially mitigate that.

Comment: Was gonna ask this, but @H2ONaCl answered it: how are you sure those leases are for no consideration (payment)? The quote you gave doesn't say that.

Comment: @Fizz  A quote from the article... "land ministry assured homeowners in Wenzhou, a city in the eastern Zhejiang province, last December that they would not have to pay a renewal fee to continue to use their residences after the shorter 20-year lease expires". It remains to be seen what will happen to the 70 year leases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allowing private land ownership was an uncomfortable option in the early PRC regime since it seemed to be at odds with Communist principles with large landholdings by old regime aristocrats presenting a particular problem to remaking society free of those hereditary inequalities.

Only long after other capitalist reforms was the 2007 Property law that allowed *de facto* real property ownership under long term leases allowed. The long term leases allowed ordinary people to become *de facto* home owners, without actually having large amounts of outright private ownership of land. And, China doesn't have the bureaucratic infrastructure to managed widespread outright property ownership by ordinary people.

Widespread leasehold rather than widespread outright ownership of homes has also helped to facilitate the condemnation of homes for public works that are springing up in China like crazy (e.g. new roads and rail lines).

A typical U.S. county, of which the U.S. has about 3000, has three different elected officials - a treasurer, a clerk and recorder, and an assessor, devoted to maintain the private real property ownership system and related property taxes, in addition to a sheriff and courts whose roles include adjudicating real property disputes. China doesn't have the vast, technical and detailed grass roots bureaucratic system and corps of real estate title professionals in place that the U.S. and other Western countries do.

China also has only a very thin set of legal statutes, cases, and rules to deal with the nitty gritty of widespread outright property ownership and doesn't have the equivalent of either a registered title system or a title insurance system that is robust enough to handle the volume of transactions that there would be if there was widespread outright property ownership.

The leases operate as a *de facto* property tax, which China doesn't have, to fund local governments in much the same way as property taxes due in the U.S. Until a property tax system is established, local governments need some way to generate base revenues to provide basic services, so simply converting the leases to outright ownership before establishing a property tax system would be problematic.

Comment: Why doesn't China have a property tax system yet?

Comment: Because they don't have significant privately-held property to tax with it. (And it sounds like the government isn't really interested in *replacing* its lease system, only fixing potential issues.)

Comment: Media have reported local governments get revenue from the "sale" of land which is the transaction that sees the trade of a lump sum for the long-term but not permanent right to occupy. Media have created an impression quite different from a lease that contracts monthly rental payments. So different, they call it a "sale" of land. The leases are for huge amounts of money compared to monthly and annual incomes.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this, but according to one [source](https://www.oecd.org/china/42607972.pdf) [footnote on  p. 9], the leases (up to 80 years) were introduced in 1988 (rather than 2007).

Comment: @Fizz According to the linked Forbes article, the 2007 law established the right to renew.

Comment: I see. Different issue.

Comment: @Sayaman There has been political deadlock over enacting one despite discussions about doing so for a long time. It may have something to do with the infrastructure needed to have one that I discuss or there may be other considerations.

Answer (score 4):

Even if the lease is for no consideration (=payment), which may or may not be the case for all leases in China, giving the land to someone in perpetuity [as property] means the old owner doesn't really have any more powers to decide anything about that land. Giving it to the lessor for a fixed term means that the actual owner (i.e. the state in this case) can give it to somebody else at the very least when the lease expires, or possibly earlier if the terms of the lease are breached. (IDK a lot about China's legal system, but generally speaking [elsewhere] a lease can have terms even if it's for no consideration, and the breach of those terms can result in early termination of the lease.

BTW, a quick look into some other [source](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/05/10/business/china-property-tax.html#:%7E:text=In%20China%2C%20where%20the%20government,plunged%20in%20the%20past%20year.) reveals that insofar it's the lease renewals that have been free of charge [seemingly in most cases], but not the initial acquisition of the lease by a construction company. So, it's not at all like giving away land for free. It more or less works like a sale, but with the caveat that there's no guarantee that future lease renewals will be free, although the Chinese real estate market insofar has priced things according to such expectations, e.g. there's no spread between 20- and 70-year leases for similar dwellings, according to [another](https://www.acuitykp.com/blog/chinas-tax-and-real-estate-debt-crises/) source.